# What SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue really does?

Tags: .net, t-sql, sql-injection, sqlcommand, escaping

What changes `SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue()` does with the query?

I expect that:

1. It replaces every `'` character by `''`,
2. If a parameter value is a string or something which must be converted to a string, it surrounds the value by `'`, so for example `select * from A where B = @hello` will give `select * from A where B = 'hello world'`.
3. If a parameter value is something "safe" like an integer, it is inserted in a query as is, without quotes, so `select * from A where B = @one` would give `select * from A where B = 1`.

Is there any other changes I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ADO.NET SqlClient driver will **not** do any replacements! That's a common misconception - it avoids the trouble of replacing anything.

What it does is pass your query with the parameters `@param1 ... @paramN` straight to SQL Server, along with a collection of parameter name/value pairs. SQL Server then executes those using the `sp_executesql` stored proc.

No replacements are ever done, there's no "stringing together the complete SQL statement" on the client side - nothing like that. If that's what the ADO.NET runtime were doing, it, too, would be very susceptible to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that using it adds a value to the end of the SqlParameterCollection, while making your parameter value safe from SQL Injection.

The MSDN documentation does not document the method's exact internal behaviors, and I doubt that it does what you describe.  However, if you wish, you can view the source code for the method using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and see exactly what it does.

Comment: Instead of reflector, use SQL Profiler.  It's faster and you'll see exactly what hits the sql server.

Comment: @Chris: That will give you the end product of course (the generated SQL statement), but it won't describe the algorithm by which that product gets assembled.