# How use WHERE in SqlDataAdapter in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

How use `WHERE` in `SqlDataAdapter` in C#?

I want get name in a textbox and use that at query but it wont work .

```
SqlConnection sqlconnection = new SqlConnection("Server=Behnam\\Accounting;Initial Catalog=Accounting;Integrated Security=TRUE");

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string _search_name = txt_search.Text;

SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT dbo.tbl_user.field1,dbo.tbl_user.field2 FROM tbl_user WHERE dbo.tbl_user.name=_search_name ", sqlconnection);

SDA.Fill(dt);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Use sql parameters as stated in some answers. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx . This prevents sql injection http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: In response to your question (from the comment of your now deleted answer) of how `addwithvalue` prevents sql injection, take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243194/what-sqlcommand-parameters-addwithvalue-really-does/3243210#3243210

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prepare the command text and use a parameter for the value of your search. 
Then use that command text to initialize a new `SqlCommand`. Fill the parameter value with `AddWithValue` and pass the SqlCommand to the constructor of the `SqlDataAdapter`.

```
string cmdText = "SELECT dbo.tbl_user.field1,dbo.tbl_user.field2 " +  
                 "FROM tbl_user WHERE dbo.tbl_user.name=@search_name"
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, sqlconnection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search_name", _search_name);
SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```

The `SqlDataAdapter` will store your command as the `SelectCommand` property and will use the passed in SqlCommand to execute the query to retrieve the records from the database.

Keep in mind that AddWithValue is a shortcut with some drawbacks. For example it pass Always a string as a nvarchar parameter with size equal to the actual lenght of the variable. This effectively reduces the performance of the Sql Server Optimizer.

This is a very enlightening [article on the issue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

So, you were pretty close, you just needed to define a parameter inside the query and then add that parameter. However, in the following code block I've also conveniently recommended a more appropriate approach to `using` the classes needed to get the data (pun intended). The `using` statement here ensures that the objects get disposed of properly after you are done using them (man I just can't stop with the puns!)

```
using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    c.Open();
    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(
        "SELECT dbo.tbl_user.field1, dbo.tbl_user.field2 FROM tbl_user " +
        "WHERE dbo.tbl_user.name= @name", c))
    {
        sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txt_search.Text);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.
you were using the string directly in the query which will go undetected.

```
SqlConnection sqlconnection = new SqlConnection("Server=Behnam\\Accounting;
Initial Catalog=Accounting;Integrated Security=TRUE");
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT dbo.tbl_user.field1,dbo.tbl_user.field2 FROM tbl_user WHERE dbo.tbl_user.name=@searchName" , sqlconnection);
SDA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchName", txt_search.Text);        
SDA.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: I just deleted my comment and gave you +1 now ;)